# What is 'MarkDependentCodeForDeoptimization()' used for in V8's Mark-Compact phase?

Tags: garbage-collection, weak-references, embedded-object, deoptimization

After Debugging in the V8 source code, I really cannot figure out what is the `MarkDependentCodeForDeoptimization();` which is called in function `MarkCompactCollector::ClearNonLiveReferences()` used for?

I find it will clear the references of weak objects embedded in JIT optimized code.

What is a `weak_object` and what dose it mean by `embedded_object` can it be a simple Smi Or String? And the most important thing is, what is the realtionship with deoptimization?

It will be more helpful if you can provided an example of js code with simple string's definition and operation.